# List of maps to a map with summing up values

Tags: elixir

I have this:

```
a1 = [%{id: 1, val: 12}, %{id: 3, val: 7}, %{id: 1, val: 5}, %{id: 2, val: 3}, %{id: 2, val: 5}], %{id: 1, val: 3}]
```

How can I get this?

```
%{
    1 => 20,
    2 => 8,
    3 => 7
  }
```

That is, a sum of "val" of each item grouped by "id"

Should I first actually group them by "id"?

```
Enum.group_by a1, &(&1.id)

  # =>

  %{
    1 => [%{id: 1, val: 12}, %{id: 1, val: 3}, %{id: 1, val: 5}],
    2 => [%{id: 2, val: 3}, %{id: 2, val: 5}],
    3 => [%{id: 3, val: 7}]
  }
```

And then do `map` and `reduce` on each item? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8):

I'd do it like this, with a single `Enum.reduce/3` call:

```
[%{id: 1, val: 12}, %{id: 3, val: 7}, %{id: 1, val: 5}, %{id: 2, val: 3}, %{id: 2, val: 5}, %{id: 1, val: 3}]
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn %{id: id, val: val}, map ->
  Map.update(map, id, val, &(&1 + val))
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{1 => 20, 2 => 8, 3 => 7}
```

This should be much more efficient than `group_by` + `map` + `reduce`.

Comment: why name a variable "map"?

Comment: No reason other than that's what came to my mind when I was writing the answer. `acc` would be a better name here.

Comment: Does the code not work for you? (You removed the upvote and un-accepted the answer.)

Comment: Worked for me with a bit of gentle nudging to accommodate for my own use case. Thanks @Dogbert !